# Is using "new" in recyclerview onBind method a bad practice?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have noticed more memory get allocated as I move up and down the recyclerview again and again, moving multiple times the memory consumption can go up to 100MB, my thought is maybe I'm creating too many objects.

I have to display date of an item, so in onBindViewHolder i call this function

```
 public void displayDate(MessageViewHolder holder, int position){
        DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(getMessage(position).getSentDate());
        DateTimeFormatter builder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
        String currentDateString = builder.print(currentDate);

        holder.date.setText(currentDateString);
        holder.date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /*
          Display date only if the next message is not mine, or its date
          is different to the current message by 1 min
        */
        if(position+1<messages.size() && (getMessage(position+1).isMine() == getMessage(position).isMine())){
            DateTime nextDate = new DateTime(getMessage(position+1).getSentDate());
            if(builder.print(nextDate).equals(currentDateString)) {
                holder.date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
 }
```

Judging from the code, what I think is everytime I scroll up or down, since this method is called from onBindViewHolder then the date objects get created all the time since I use "new", thus leading to the memory allocation increase everytime I scroll up and down again.

Is it a bad practice to call "new" in onBindViewHolder? 
Or am I over optimizing stuffs and should leave the GC to do its job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate many objects in ViewHolder bind method is not a good pratice for performances. If you do too much work, the RecyclerView behaviour become slow and the scroll become not linear. In your example there isn't a too expensive work in my opinion, but you could optimize the code saving timestamp in data model item. Then if item.date == null create objects and save to model, otherwise retrieve data value from model.

To check if new instances are causing memory leaks, comment the code and observe memory consuming while scrolling.